# Zsh: test newline in case

Tags: zsh

```
# user input a here
vared -p "input something" -c a
case $a { ([y|'\n']) echo something;; }
```

won't work, can someone give an insight?

I'm trying to test against user input that if contain `y` or an `enter` - newline, echo something.

EDIT:

```
set | grep IFS
IFS=$' \t\n\C-@'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saying how you're getting user input.

With `read`:

```
read -k 'answer?Are you OK? '
case $answer in
  (y | Y | $'\n') echo 1;;
  # or ([$'yY\n']) echo 1;;
  (*)         echo 2;;
esac
```

But if you're using `read` without `-k` or `vared` and want to detect when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering any answer, that's when you would want to test for an empty value:

```
answer=; vared -p 'Are you OK? ' answer
case $answer in
  (y | Y | "") echo 1;;
  # or ([yY] | "") echo 1;;
  (*)         echo 2;;
esac
```

Or seed the answer with `y` (though the user would have to do <kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to say *no*):

```
answer=y; vared -p 'Are you OK? ' answer
case $answer in
  (y | Y) echo 1;;
  (*)     echo 2;;
esac
```

Comment: I used `vared -p "input something" -c a` to get input, I don't think your answer works for me. Did I miss something?

Comment: @TuyenPham, `vared` is to edit the content of a variable. To get a newline character into that variable, the user would have to type Ctrl+V Ctrl+J, or Alt+Enter, is that really what you want? Or do you want to check whether the user has entered an empty input (like when they press Enter when the editing buffer is empty)?

Comment: Yes, with `vared` that I mentioned above I'd like to capture that user input is `enter` or not? if `enter` echo something. Because `-c` I believe the variable is create if not exist. I only check for `enter` not an empty input like `space`.

Comment: @TuyenPham, it's still unclear what you want. "Enter" in `vared` is for accepting the current value. You also need to press "Enter" after having edited the variable value so as to contain "y" or "n" (for instance by pressing "y" or "n" if the variable was initially empty). Pressing space adds a space character to the content of the variable, it makes it non-empty. Do you want to check that the user didn't modify the value of the variable?

Comment: `vared -p "input something" -c a` and user doesn't input anything but `enter` then I'd need to capture this to echo something. I mean user tries to default `enter` to `y`.

Comment: @TuenPham, sounds like you want `a=y; vared -p "input something: " a`

Comment: True, but now how to change colors of `vared -p` options, can you give a help in `https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468955/256195`?