# Zsh: change color of vared -p command

Tags: zsh

I tried:

```
vared -p '"$(print \"\e[1;31test\")" something' -c tmp
```

Output echo `"$(print \"\e[1;31test\")" something`

But I want to change color of `test` word here. Howto achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `-p` understands prompt expansion, so it's just:

```
var=; vared -p '%B%F{red}something%f: ' var
```

- `%B`: `bold` (`%b` to stop bold)
- `%F{red}`: red foreground (`%K` for bacKground).
- `%f`: restore default foreground color.

Doing:

```
vared -p $'\e[1;31msomething: ' var
```

which would be equivalent to `vared -p "$(printf '\e[1;31msomething: ')"` (corrected from the version in your question) would be a bad idea as it would fool `zle`'s cursor positioning by letting it think that the prompt is 18 columns wide while in fact it's only 11 columns wide as `\e[1;31m` is not visible.

Comment: I've just learn `%f` and `%B`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve this by using double quotes after `-p` and load `colors` module of zsh.

Comment: This is not an answer, and fit for a comment. So remove your answer and add it as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be in the direction of an answer; Tuyen, maybe write out the corrected command, so it’s clear what worked for you?